# How can do use web3.eth.Contract()?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, react

I am using web3 version 1.3.6.

But some people said it can use version 0.20.1.

If I use 0.20.1, I can not use other functions.

Other Method?

Comment: Use web3 1.3.6, there's no reason to use 0.20.x, it is no longer maintained.

Comment: But, In web3 version 1.3.6, I can not use web3.eth.Contract(), How do you use this function? If I use web3.eth.Contract(), it occurs error - web3.eth.Contract is not a function. for example `const NameContract = web3.eth.Contract(contract_abi, contract_address);`

Comment: The latest web3 version is 1.3.4. `Contract` is a type so you have to use new to create an instance, like `let myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);`. For an example check the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#example).